# What does the TSA do with confiscated liquids?

Tags: usa, hand-luggage, tsa

So, we all know that if your carry-on has a liquid in excess of the prescribed size amounts (typically 3 oz), you can't take it on board.

Presumably, these things are destroyed, but I wonder, are there any charities who reuse these liquids for shelters and others who need them?  Abused women's shelter, in particular, are often seeking cosmetics and the like - and I can imagine that many of the other liquids could be safely repurposed, not to mention the knives, lighters, and scissors.

Is there be a procedure whereby a charity could request to use these items? Who would one contact to find out - the local airport or some central office in DC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are blogs on the subject of what actually happens with the confiscated items:

- [The Week](http://theweek.com/article/index/253351/what-does-the-tsa-do-with-your-confiscated-stuff)
- [TSA](http://blog.tsa.gov/2009/09/what-happens-to-your-prohibited-items.html)

and there are a few others.  Basically TSA confiscated items that can be resold are being resold through the Surplus program run by the state where the airport is located.

So for example in Pennsylvania [Department of General Services Surplus Operations](http://www.dgs.state.pa.us/portal/server.pt/community/supplies_and_surplus_operations/1393) administers such a program, so if you want buy something it would either be at the Harrisburg Warehouse or listed on [GovDeals](http://www.govdeals.com).

Comment: Many (most?) liquids just end up in a trash can near the checkpoint, which is pretty ironic if you think about the policy being to reduce explosives being taken on board.

Comment: If a terroist sets off a bomb on the ground then the only people nomally killed are those directly killed by the bomb blast or shrapnel, if they set of a bomb on a plane there is a real chance of them bringing down the whole plane.